# Realtek 8190 wireless doesn't work

Tags: wireless, realtek

I have a Realtek RTL 8190 (802.11n) Wireless controller.

```
> lspci -v | grep Network
04:01.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 8190
```

I first installed the driver rtl8192se_linux_2.6.0010.1012.2009_64bit.tar.gz, but apparently that does not work for the 8190.

On searching deeper, I found that I should use `ndiswrapper` with the Windows drivers, [following these instructions](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1606676). I downloaded the 64-bit drivers, installed them with ndiswrapper, and verified that the installation worked:

```
$ ndiswrapper -l
net819xp : driver installed
    device (10EC:8190) present
```

But still the driver does not work:

```
$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

I read that I needed to execute `sudo modprobe ndiswrapper` to start it, but that didn't change a thing.

Does anybody have any insights? Is the rtl8192se driver maybe conflicting? How do I remove that one?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9941361&postcount=5)

Step 1:- Install NDISWrapper and Blacklist Native Driver

```
echo -e 'blacklist rtl8190\nblacklist wl' | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist
sudo apt-get install ndiswrapper-utils-1.9
mkdir ~/rtl8190; cd ~/rtl8190
```

***Note bodhi.zazen - You probably need to reboot after blacklisting wl ;)***

Step 2: Copy (the windows drivers) "rtl8190p.sys" and "net8190.inf" to ~/rtl8190

Step 3: Configure NDISWrapper (and WPA Supplicant)

```
sudo ndiswrapper -i net8190.inf
ndiswrapper -l
sudo depmod -a
sudo modprobe ndiswrapper
sudo cp /etc/network/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces.orig
echo -e 'auto lo\niface lo inet loopback\n' | sudo tee /etc/network/interfaces
sudo ndiswrapper -m
echo 'ndiswrapper' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
echo 'ENABLED=0' | sudo tee -a /etc/default/wpasupplicant
```